# Rails + postgres autoincrement not updated on explicit id inserts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm with the same problem of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108833/postgres-autoincrement-not-updated-on-explicit-id-inserts). But I'm using Rails and don't know how to do this workaround in activerecord.

I'm inserting some data using seeds.rb:

```
device_platforms = DevicePlatform.create([{id: 1, name: 'Android'}, {id: 2, name: 'IOS'}, {id: 3, name: 'Windows Phone'}])
```

When I insert another DevicePlatform, I get this exception:

```
Failure/Error: @device_platform = FactoryGirl.create(:device_platform)
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
   PG::UniqueViolation: ERRO:  duplicar valor da chave viola a restrição de unicidade "device_platforms_pkey"                                                                 
   DETAIL:  Chave (id)=(2) já existe.
   : INSERT INTO "device_platforms" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"
```

The message is in portuguese, it says that a row with that ID already exists.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you specifying the id?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you're calling `create`, so you're "going to the database".  What about your code would not work if you just had `{ name: 'Android' }, { name: 'IOS' }`, etc in the seeds create call?

Comment: Don't include `id`s in your seeds. If you must include `id`s in your seeds then you'll have to `connection.execute` the SQL in the other question after adding your seeds.

Comment: I'm building a rails API. According to the request user_agent, I know from what platform the user request is comming. If I don't especify the id, I need on every request to go to the database and search by the name to get this ID. Don't know if it's the best way. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for including the exact text of the error. I'd +100 if I could.

Comment: @muistooshort You think include ids on seeds file is a bad practice?

Comment: @NickVeys My "going to the database" message was sent wrong. Hitted the enter button unintentionally. :)

Comment: Depending on `id`s being anything in particular is a bad practice. You can do it if you need to but you will need to run some SQL to patch up the sequences that are used to supply `id` values.

Comment: @muistooshort Thank you. Please, post it as an answer to I can set as accepted.

Comment: @WilliamWeckl you should be hitting the db with a `find_by(name: 'xxx')` if you really want the id. The real question is why do you have a table with just that in it? If it is to define the apps behaviour then you already have the information in the request, as you have stated.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

According to the comments, using id in seed is a bad practice. I'm avoiding bad practices and that's enough for me. Changed my code to avoiding this.

Comment: There are still valid use cases where this can happen (for example, reading in a CSV file in your rake task), so it'd be nice to see a valid answer for how to solve this.

Comment: Please accept the answer above as it does answer the question you have asked, even though it is a bad idea. Sometimes doing bad things is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that although this is a bad habit, many times it is the only resort

You can define this method :

```
def fix_self_increment(model)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
    "BEGIN; " \
    "LOCK TABLE #{model.table_name} IN EXCLUSIVE MODE; " \
    "SELECT setval('#{model.table_name}_id_seq', COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM #{model.table_name}), 1), false); " \
    "COMMIT;"
  )
end
```

and then call

```
fix_self_increment(DevicePlatform)
```

Enjoy

Comment: I'd put this code in every migration of data that does this kind of insert rather than having a method that does it. It quickly teaches you it's a bad idea to specify id. This is the correct answer btw.