# Python/ Django Key already exists. Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I Have a project built in django and it uses a postgres database.
This database was populated by CSVs files. So when I want to insert a new object I got the error "duplicated key" because the object with id = 1 already exists.

The code :

```
user = User(name= "Foo")
user.save()
```

The table users has the PK on the id.

```
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

If I get the table's details in psql I got:

```
Column| Type    |  Modifiers                          
------+-------- +--------------------------------------
id    | integer | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Additionally, if I do *user.**dict*** after create the variable user and before saving it, I get *'id': None*

How can I save the user with an id that is not being used?

Answer (score 11):

You most likely inserted your Users from the CSV setting the id value explicitly, when this happens the postgres sequence is not updated and as a result of that when you try to add a new user the sequence generates an already used value

Check this other question for reference [postgres autoincrement not updated on explicit id inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108833/postgres-autoincrement-not-updated-on-explicit-id-inserts)

The solution is what the answer for that question says, update your sequence manually

Answer (score 8):

You can fix it by setting users_id_seq manually.

```
SELECT setval('users_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) from "users"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have name as a primary key for the table the above insert should work. If you have name as primary key remove it and try it.

Comment: No, the PK is the id.   Indexes: "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id).

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres SQL you can specify id as serial and you can mark it as Primary Key.Then whenever you will insert record , it will be in a sequence.
i.e id serial NOT NULL and 
CONSTRAINT primkey PRIMARY KEY (id).

As you said its a pre populated by CSV , so when you insert it from python code it will automatically go the end of the table and there will be no duplicate values.

Comment: The id is set as serial take a look at the description, I updated the question and put what psql says about the table

Comment: Use cursor.lastrowid to get the last row ID inserted on the cursor object, or connection.insert_id() to get the ID from the last insert on that connection.