# С# + linqtodb + postgres DB - insert identity in table

Tags: c#, postgresql

There is a table in the postgres DB:

```
CREATE TABLE "tbl"
(
    "id" bigint generated always as identity
        constraint pk_key primary key
);
```

I can insert id with some value by sql script:

```
INSERT INTO contracts.loan_contracts1 (id)
OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE -- this allow me insert id value 
VALUES (10);
```

Entity for LinqToDb:

```
[Table("tbl", Schema = "public")]
public class TblEntity : IIdentifiable<long>
{
    [Column("id")]
    [PrimaryKey]
    [Identity]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

How to enforce linqToDB to create query with hint - "OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE"?

```
connection.InsertWithId( new TblEntity(){id = 10});
```

throw en error

MessageText: cannot insert into column "id"
Detail: Column "id" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.
Hint: Use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE to override.

```
If create id like:
"id" bigint generated by default as identity 
and remove attribute [Identity] from Entity definition, 
then it would work, 

but I need:
1 - use attribute [Identity] for Entity
2 - use LinqToDb ORM to create query
```

and I don't want to use LinqToDB syntax like this:

```
 connection.tbl.
   Value(p => p.Id, 10)
   .Insert());
```

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701029/how-to-insert-value-to-identity-column-in-postgresql-11-1. Instead of using "GENERATED ALWAYS" try  "GENERATED BY DEFAULT" so u can insert your custom Id.

Comment: I've  mention that way in question, I need to use entity with attribute [Identity] and use LInqToDB ORM