# How to get auto increment identity column working

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

We are using EF Core, but we also upgrade pre-ef core databases to the latest version. On Postegres there is a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "DatabaseVersion"  
( 
    "DatabaseVersionId" integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ) PRIMARY KEY, 
    "Version"     varchar(20) NOT NULL,  
    "VersionDate" timestamptz NULL DEFAULT Now(), 
    "Description" varchar(2000) NULL, 
    "AppliedDate" timestamptz NULL DEFAULT Now()
);
```

In PgAdmin, I create a database and this table, then I insert into the table for a test using:

```sql
INSERT INTO "DatabaseVersion" ("Version") 
VALUES ('1.0.0.0');
```

and I get the first row entered then I can change the version in the insert statement and insert more rows. Each row has a unique `DatabaseVersionId`.

However, when I run the upgrade and attempt to insert a value using EF Core, I get an exception

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint

I created a new database to see how EF Core defined the key and it is:

```sql
GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1).
```

I added primary key to that to avoid adding a lot of primary key constraints to our older scripts.

Our update code is shown here (`T` would be `DatabaseVersion`):

```cs
var dbSet = context.Set<T> ();

var id = GetKey (context, item);

if (id == 0)
{
    dbSet.Add (item);
}
else
{
    var p = dbSet.Find (id);
    dbSet.Attach (p);

    var a = context.Entry (p);

    if (a != null)
        a.CurrentValues.SetValues (item);
}

context.SaveChanges ();
```

What needs to be done to older scripts to make the identity primary key work?

Or is that even the problem? I am not a postgres expert.

Our database upgrade uses scripts until it gets to a certain version, then we run each [migration individually](https://makolyte.com/ef-core-apply-migrations-programmatically/). EF Core figures out not to run the initial create migration on its own, but it still adds an entry in the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table, which is great.

**Update**

In my searches I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108833/postgres-autoincrement-not-updated-on-explicit-id-inserts). During our update and create of a new database we insert data that has the primary key already set, so with postgresql the sequence is not updated and on your first insert your get a duplicate key exception. To get around this after a create or upgrade of a databse you can use the following script:

```
                @"SELECT setval( 
                  (SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence( '""<%SchemaName%>"".""<%TableName%>""', '<%KeyName%>')),
                  (SELECT MAX(""<%KeyName%>"") from ""<%SchemaName%>"".""<%TableName%>""),
                  true );";
```

Using this in a loop with table and primary key name all sequences can be set to their proper value.

Comment: Just notice, why `dbSet.Attach (p);`? Entity already attached.

Comment: We are using disconnected entities so we need to attach

Comment: `dbSet.Find` returns tracked entity.

Comment: Right but we are disconnected so not tracked

Comment: After your update: does that mean the question is answered? If so, please add the update as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sorry Gert. I hate self answering questions. Should I add an answer that says look at update?